# sfdisk/parted: predictable/predefined partuuid for msdos partition table

Tags: boot, partition, mbr

When GPT is used partition ID can be set with `sgdisk`

```
$ sgdisk --partition-guid=1:"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" "/dev/vda"
$ readlink -f /dev/disk/by-partuuid/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
/dev/vda1
```

How can I use a predefined partition id with MSDOS partition table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ID=00000001 # Disk identifier
$
                (
                    echo x # Expert mode
                    echo i # Change disk indentifier
                    echo 0x"$ID" # New identifier
                    echo r # Return
                    echo w # Write
                    echo q # Quit
                ) | fdisk "/dev/vda"

$  readlink -f /dev/disk/by-partuuid/"$ID"-01      
/dev/vda1
```